# can't push the value properly

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I tried rewriting it, Doesn't look too different, but in order to work, this is what I had to come up with.
I included the html, css, and javascript files bellow. Maybe you can run it on your side and give a feedback. It still not running on my end. Maybe that would be it, just not running on MY end.


PS: I use (i += 1) instead of (i++) because I can read it better that way.

JavaScript: jsmain.js

```
var gate = 0;
var count = [];
var daLink = []
var howMany = document.getElementById("howmany").value;

function addAnInput(){
    document.getElementById("newholder").innerHTML += "Inser Link: <input class='boxes' id='gate" + gate.toString() + "' type='text' size='83' /><br />";
    count.push(gate);
    gate += 1;
}

function getValues(){
    daLink = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count.length; i += 1){
        daLink.push(document.getElementById("gate" + i));
    };
    for (i = 0; i < howmany; i += 1){
        function thisNow(){return Math.floor(Math.random() * daLink.length)};
        var thisOne = thisNow;
        window.open(daLink[thisOne], "_blank");
    }
}
```

HTML: index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DMA Link opener</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="jsmain.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssmain.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="title">
        <h1>DMA Link opener</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="button-holder">
            <p id="add-button" onClick="addAnInput()">Add Link</p>
            <p id="runit" onClick="getValues()">Run It</p>
            <input id="howmany" type="number" min="1" max="5" />
        </div>
        <form id="newholder"></form>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS: cssmain.css

```
h1{
    width: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0 20px 0 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightgray, lightblue);
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}

.separator{
    width: 70%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.button-holder{
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Calibri;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}

#add-button{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 175, 180), lightblue);
}

#runit{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(0, 175, 180), lightblue);
}

#newholder{
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input{
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.boxes{
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    background: gray;
}

.boxes:hover{
    background: lightblue;
}

.boxes:focus{
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    background: rgb(0, 175, 180);
}

#howmany{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: which part of the code is giving you problems?

Comment: my guess would be within the first for loop in the whichOne() function. whenever I remove the pushing actions,the tabs are opening (with no value of course).

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem? http://jsfiddle.net ? or perhaps stacksnippets itself?

Comment: There has to be something that is causing it not to run. Does your console have any errors?

Comment: Normally it should run. A few days ago, I declared the inputs in the html and the daLink array values were already designated and manually pushed and worked with flying colors. But once I inserted the "Add" function in order to add as many inputs as I want, that's when the code didn't work. But even with such a difference, since the "Add" function works but the rest of the actions don't, that's where it rendered me confused. So, in theory, the code above should be good. However, I'm missing something and I can't see what.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var gate = 0;
var count = [];
var daLink = [];
function addAnInput(){
    document.getElementById("newholder").innerHTML += "Inser Link: <input class='boxes' id='gate" + gate.toString() + "' type='text' size='83' /><br />";
    count.push(gate);
    gate += 1;
}
function thisNow(){return Math.floor(Math.random() * daLink.length)};
function getValues(){
 var howMany = document.getElementById("howmany").value;
    daLink = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i += 1){
        daLink.push(document.getElementById("gate" + i).value);
    };
    for (var i = 0; i <howMany; i += 1){
        var thisOne = thisNow();
        window.open(daLink[thisOne], "_blank");
    }
}
```

```css
h1{
    width: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0 20px 0 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightgray, lightblue);
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}

.separator{
    width: 70%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.button-holder{
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Calibri;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}

#add-button{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 175, 180), lightblue);
}

#runit{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(0, 175, 180), lightblue);
}

#newholder{
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input{
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.boxes{
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    background: gray;
}

.boxes:hover{
    background: lightblue;
}

.boxes:focus{
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    background: rgb(0, 175, 180);
}

#howmany{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>DMA Link opener</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="jsmain.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssmain.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="title">
        <h1>DMA Link opener</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="button-holder">
            <p id="add-button" onClick="addAnInput()">Add Link</p>
            <p id="runit" onClick="getValues()">Run It</p>
            <input id="howmany" type="number" min="1" max="5" />
        </div>
        <form id="newholder"></form>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

so yeah little explanation...
1- the code is on `<head>` so its running before the body loaded so `howMany` is being set to null as there is no element.
2- the fuction 'thisNow' is being created every time you run `getValues` it's not a good pratice (actually neither is the `document.getElementById("newholder")` everytime you run `addAnInput` but for the sake of Simplicity I left it there).
3- the function `thisNow` is never actually called, you are setting  `thisOne` to a function.
4- in the for loops its better to use `var i`, as just `i` is actually setting a global variable, it could lead to errors.
5- there was a typo in the last for loop `howMany` was written `howmany`

Comment: I do want daLink to reset, as the whichOne() function would be called by the "Run It" button. The idea is to reset daLink's values and re-add them, otherwise, the second for loop would run an additional set of values from daLink which I do not wish to add. By the way, I copy-pasted the code so I can run it. It does not work. On the snippet above does.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work from the stack snippet, but it works.I think now I got what you wanted

Comment: I tried the new one. Still not running. I rewrote it from the beginning but ended up writing almost the same thing. Guess that would be exactly what I want in order to work. But it's not. I edited the initial question and added all the files. Maybe I'm missing something elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you @shadownrun. This actually did the trick. I wasn't aware about the error thisNow() was bringing and I was inexcusable forgetting about i being set to global. Thanks you and I appreciate it.